# How to Read more than 1 JsonObject in a Json file

Tags: java, json

Hello Im using Gson library and i have a class named Estudiante.class and i have a Json file
that looks like this. Im using Eclipse (Java) MAC OS X.

```
{"nombre":"Alex","apellido":"S","cedula":"1234","mes":2,"ano":2,"dia":2,"zona":"LSM","telefono":"0000","semestre":5,"promedio":5.0}
{"nombre":"Alfred","apellido":"S","cedula":"523412","mes":6,"ano":6,"dia":6,"zona":"LSM","telefono":"0001","semestre":6,"promedio":6.0}
```

Now i want to read that and put it into a Estudiante Array with position 1 Alex and position 2 Alfred (and so on if i have more Objects).

Can any1 help me on this implementation. I've read thousands of topics and can't figure out what im doing wrong. Thanks.

Estudiante estudiantes[] = new Estudiante[20];

public void leerJson(){

```
    int i=0;
    int contador=0;
    try {
         JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("estudiantes.json"));

         while (reader.hasNext()) {

             String name = reader.nextName();
             estudiantes[i]=new Estudiante();


              if (name.equals("nombre")) { 
                  estudiantes[i].setNombre(reader.nextString());

              } else if (name.equals("apellido")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setApellido(reader.nextString());


              } else if (name.equals("cedula")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setCedula(reader.nextString());

              } else if (name.equals("mes")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setMes(Integer.parseInt(reader.nextString()));

              } else if (name.equals("ano")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setAno(Integer.parseInt(reader.nextString()));

              }else if (name.equals("dia")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setDia(Integer.parseInt(reader.nextString()));

              } else if (name.equals("telefono")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setTelefono(reader.nextString());

              } else if (name.equals("semestre")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setSemestre(Integer.parseInt(reader.nextString()));

              } else if (name.equals("promedio")) {
                  estudiantes[i].setPromedio(Double.parseDouble(reader.nextString()));
                  i++;
              } else {
                reader.skipValue(); //avoid some unhandle events
              }


            }

            reader.endObject();
            reader.close();

             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.out.println("asdsa");
            e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("vrvrt");
            e.printStackTrace();
             }

}
```

}
Thats My progress

Comment: Share what you have tried so far.

Comment: What you have is independent JSON strings back-to-back.  I don't think you can read it using NSJSONSerialization unless you pre-process and split into individual lines.

Comment: Well, Jackson can read such files; not sure about Gson. But that's a pretty lame way of storing JSON in any case...

Comment: Are you generating the JSON output somewhere or is it provided in that format from another source?  Ideally it would be serialized as an array rather than separate JSON strings when writing to the file.

Comment: I don't know how to do it another way. I just started using Json yesterday and can't seem to figure out how to read more than 1 objects on a Json File and put it into my normal JavaArray which is Estudiante estudiantes[]

Comment: Huh, yesterday? OK, can you change libraries? If yes, I'll give you an example with Jackson...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once made one exercise like that one while I was at the university, I used ArrayList for my purposes, you could try something like this (I worked with Pokemon since at that time I made my exercises that way, was more didactic, at least for me):

```
List<PokemonBean> plist = new ArrayList<PokemonBean>();
PokemonBean p1 = new PokemonBean();
p1.setNumber(1);
p1.setName("Bulbasaur");
p1.setType("Grass");

PokemonBean p2 = new PokemonBean();
p2.setNumber(25);
p2.setName("Pikachu");
p2.setType("Electric");

plist.add(p1);
plist.add(p2);

Gson agson = new Gson();
Type myListType = new TypeToken<List<PokemonBean>>(){}.getType();
String myJsonString = agson.toJsonTree(plist, myListType);
```

And if you want to read, you can do it the same way:

```
Type myListType = new TypeToken<List<PokemonBean>>(){}.getType();
List<Pokemon> myListAgain = agson.fromJson(json, myListType);
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Regards and happy coding :).